# Laravel 500 error, Base64 images, Ajax and array's

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am uploading, or better said, *trying to* upload images to my Laravel website with Ajax. I convert the images to Base64 and upload them to the server. It works, sort of.

My problem is that I get a 500 error.
[image: It's the response from the server in an Iframe]

It's the response from the server in an Iframe

The thing is, I do not get this error all the times.
I only get it when I try to do something with the response.

This is my method where I handle the upload. 
When I run it like this everything works and I **do not** get the error.

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{

    return var_dump($request->all());
}
```

But it is an array. So to do something with it I have to specify the key. Only problem is that as soon I do that I get the 500 error.

I want to convert the base64 string back to an image so I want to do this:

```
file_put_contents('foo.png', base64_decode($request->all()[0]));
```

But this creates the error. the `[0]` at the end of `$request->all()`.

I can't remove it because it needs a base64 string and not an array. I also wanted to know what would happen if I just add `[0]` to the end of `$request-all()` in the var dump but I still got the errror.

I just don't get it.

This is my Ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
            url: "/admin/upload",
            type: "POST",
            data: queue,
            processData: false,
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                let err = xhr.responseText;
                //console.log(err);
                $('#upload-InnerPanel').append("<iframe width='600' height='500' src='" + err +"'> </iframe>")
            },
            success: function (xhr) {
                console.log(xhr);
            },
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use `[0]` instead of using something like `$request->yourBase64Data`, whatever that POST value is called. The post object isn't  indexed by number

Comment: Oh well, that's embarrassing..... Ofcourse I should've used that. It works now. Thanks. Might need to get some sleep.... it's getting quite late.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered in the comments, but posting this as an answer anyway:

The $request value that is received isn't numerically indexed, so you need to access it using its name. Instead of `$request->all()[0]`, you would need to use `$request->theData`, or whatever the value is named in the form.